# Question about computable function with recursive domain

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Assume there is an $x\in\mathbb{N}:dom(φ_{M_x})\in$ REC. Obviously $φ_{M_x}$ is computable and since $dom(φ_{M_x})$ can always decide if something belongs in its domain or not, doesn't that mean that $M_x$ corresponds to a decidable language? If that's true, what's the difference between saying that $φ_{M_x}\in$ REC?

Comment: What does it mean to say that a Turing machine is decidable? Normally we talk about a *set* being decidable (= computable).

Comment: Yes I am sorry I meant the corresponding language is decidable ergo $M_x$ halts for all inputs and decides the language. (fixed)